# Match cells in two sheets and copy paste the match content

Tags: excel, vba

I'm totally new to the vba. I have two excel sheets, and I'm trying to compare and match the cells in one of the columns in two sheets. If matched cells are found, information of the adjacent cells will be copied and paste to another sheet(sheet1).

I have a code that works just fine but incomplete. Because there are repetitive cells in a column, the code once finds a match and copy-paste the info, it skips to the next non-repeated cells. Thus resulting in a lot of blank, missing cell. Any idea to make it fill in the blank?

**Image:**
[image]

**Sheet2:**
[image: Sheet2]

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim lastRw1, lastRw2, nxtRw, m

  lastRw1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  lastRw2 = Sheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Loop
     For nxtRw = 2 To lastRw2
'Search
        With Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lastRw1)
          Set m = .Find(Sheets(2).Range("B" & nxtRw), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
'Copy
            If Not m Is Nothing Then
              Sheets(2).Range("C" & nxtRw & ":D" & nxtRw).Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("J" & m.Row)
            End If
        End With
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use [`FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext). That will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it possible to provide more specific detail?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

I took a small sample of your Sheet2 data set:

[image]

I also updated your code as follows (main change - I replaced Find with Match in order to find the matching row number):

```
Dim lastRw1 As Long, lastRw2 As Long, nxtRw As Long, m As Long

lastRw1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRw2 = Sheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop
 For nxtRw = 2 To lastRw1
    'Search
    With Sheets(1)
         m = Application.Match(.Range("A" & nxtRw).Value, _
                Sheets(2).Range("B1:B" & lastRw2), 0)
        'Copy
         If m Then
            Sheets(2).Range("C" & m & ":D" & m).Copy _
            Destination:=.Range("J" & nxtRw)
         End If
    End With
 Next
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried using nxtRw instead of m.Row, but it won't solve the issue. Sheet2 has the same address but without duplicates. Only sheet1 address is repetitive. The `find` function is intentional, but maybe I wrong here. Would `FindNext` help?

Comment: Hi @Mark.T, thanks for pasting the second screenshot, this is useful. I will update my answer in a minute.